# Closed form for repeated theta operator applied to $x\cos(x)$

Tags: derivatives

let $\theta_{x}$ be the operator :
$$\theta_{x}=x\frac{d}{dx}$$

> What is the closed form for :
>
> $$\theta_{x}^{n}\left[x\cos(x)\right]$$
> $n$ being an positive integer.

Comment: Try computing the case $n=1,2$ and understanding the resulting pattern

Comment: i did ... for $n=1,2,3\; \text{and}\; 4$ .. but i wasn't able to detect the pattern !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have the closed form

> $$ \sum_{k=0}^{n} {n\brace k} x^k \left(x\cos\left(x+\frac{k\pi}{2}\right)+k\sin\left(x+\frac{k\pi}{2}\right)\right),$$

where ${n\brace k}$ is the Stirling numbers of the second kind. For the $n$th derivative of $x\cos(x)$, see [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4FXAHVyGS9KZWIzZjIxZGQtN2M4NC00N2MzLTk1YmQtM2M2NmVhYmE4NzA5/edit?hl=en_US).

**Note:** We used the identity

> $$ (xD)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n}{n\brace k} x^k D^k. $$

Comment: I probably missunderstood, but for $n=1$ we should arrive at $xD(x\cos x)=x\cos x-x^2\sin x$, while using your formula I arrive at $-x\sin x+x\cos x$, as ${1\brace 0}=0$ and ${1\brace 1}=1$

Comment: @Avitus: Let me check this. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: No no, I did not see $x$ in front of $\cos(x+...)$: so the power is $x^{k+1}$. Now it is clear to me: thank you for feedback.!

Comment: I did not know that decomposition involving the Stirling numbers of second kind: it is interesting indeed

Comment: @Avitus: No problem. You made me to check the formula which is good. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal ... there is a typo in the formula above ... in the expression between brackets, n should be k.

Comment: Something must be wrong as the result should be an odd function of $x$. Furthermore $\theta^2 x\cos = x\cos -3x^2\sin-x^3\cos$ but your formula gives $-x^2\cos-2x^2\sin-x\sin-x^3\cos$.

Comment: @MohammadAlJamal: Fixed. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\theta:=\theta_x$, $f(x):=x\cos(x)$ and $g(x)=x^2\sin x$. Then

$$\theta(f)=f-g, $$
$$\theta^2(f)=\theta(f)-\theta(g)=f-g-\theta(g), $$
$$\theta^3(f)=\theta(f)-\theta(g)-\theta^2(g)=f-g-\theta(g)-\theta^2(g); $$

in summary

$$\theta^n(f)=f-g-\theta(g)-\dots-\theta^{n-1}(g).$$

Comment: So the problem $\theta^n x\cos(x)$ is "reduced" to $\theta^n x^2\sin(x)$ ...

Comment: This is the easiest form I found: I began to compute the operators $\theta^i(g)$ but I got tired quite soon...(addedunm: all depends on the specific problem of the OP and its level of detail)